# what's different between layout_gravity="top" and android:layout_alignParentTop="true"?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna put image in top of View and a listview bottom of it.
what's best and correct way?

LinearLayout?RelativeLayout?
and with which attribute?

```
layout_gravity="top"?
layout_alignParentTop="true"?
```

please give me a snipped code and a brief description about:

what's different between layout_gravity="top" and android:layout_alignParentTop="true"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanna put image in top of View and a listview bottom of it. what's
>   best and correct way?

If you want to place a `ListView` below an `ImageView` positioned at the top of the current view then you could use both layouts, it isn't any real difference.

The `layour_gravity`is used to place the children relative within its parent bounds(the `Relativelayout` doesn't have this attribute). For example you could use a `LinearLayout` with orientation `vertical` which will stack your two children one on top of the other like you want. Also `layout_gravity="top"` is ignored for a `vertical` orientated `LinearLayout` as it doesn't make sense, so you could remove it from the layout completely:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- the layout_gravity is useless int this case and could be removed--> 
    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    <ListView />
</LinearLayout>
```

`layout_alignParentTop` is a placement rule for children of `RelativeLayout`(only for this type of layout!) which tells them to position aligning the top of the children with the top of the parent `RelativeLayout`. In this case, to stack the children you would do:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- you could remove the layout_alignParentTop attribute because by default the Relativelayout will position it's children there -->
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageId" android:layout_alingParentTop="true" />
    <!-- Position this child below the other -->
    <ListView android:layout_below="@id/imageId"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if i use oriention=vertical , what's happen on landscape mode when swap mobile?

Comment: @CooLi3oY The `LinearLayout` will keep its orientation to vertical and all will be the same except the width will be bigger and the height smaller.

Comment: sry,i'm confused.it means " no problem and everythings swap? "

Comment: @CooLi3oY You could test it for yourself. The `LinearLayout` will stay the same with orientation vertical.

Comment: >>layout_gravity="top" is ignored for a vertical orientated LinearLayout<< It sure is ignored, but I wonder why, it surely makes sense. It looks I am forced to use aRelativeLayout instead due to this limitation.

Comment: @kellogs I'm not sure why do we have that behavior for `LinearLayout`, my guess is that it will be expensive/hard to calculate the children's dimensions in cases where the gravity is set along the orientation and where also weight will be used. Check this blog entry to read more about this http://sandipchitale.blogspot.ro/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html